# Can an EPS-file contain non-vectorized fonts?

Tags: fonts, eps

**Can an EPS-file with text contain non-vectorized fonts?** (meaning that the receiver needs to have the fonts in question installed) or are fonts always vectorized when I save a file as EPS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An EPS is merely a file **wrapper**. What's in that wrapper can be a mix of *either* raster *or* vector. It's also possible that an EPS contains 100% raster data and no vector data at all... or that it contains 100% vector data and no raster data at all.

Fonts, typically are vector, and when contained in a file which is then saved to a format that supports vector data (EPS, PDF, PSD, AI, etc)  they are:

- either embedded as live vector type (you can't extract the actual fonts from an EPS, or any file really. The **data** is embedded, not the actual operating system fonts.)
- outlined, creating vector paths (but without live type hinting and other features)
- possibly rasterized due to file appearances

Any one of those three is entirely possible with an EPS. The only way to know is to open the EPS after it's been saved to find out what things look like.

Comment: If they are embedded as a "live vector type", that means that there's no data about the actual font face except its name embedded in the file?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver it means the actual data for the characters are embedded not working font files. Things like hinting and kerning values, the vector outline of the glyph, it's family name and unique glyph ID. Essentially there are 2 options regarding fonts when creating a PDF - embed a subset or embed all. A "subset" means *only* the *actual* characters needed are included in the PDF. Embed all means, well, embed all characters. But in no instance is it possible to somehow extract or pull out a font file that will then operate like other fonts on the system.

Comment: The only way to eliminate *all* font data in a PDF is to outline type or rasterize it before creating the PDF. Then they are just vector shapes or pixels. For type sizes below 12pts it's sometimes unwise to outline/rasterize. Fonts contain things like hinting which tells the output device the best way to draw their shape. Without hinting smaller type may not look as good. It's generally not an issue for 12pts or larger though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes an EPS can contain live, editable text and therefore this would necessitate the correct font being available to successfully edit it and maintain the intended appearance.

No, fonts are not vectorised by default in an EPS file.