# Can I alter the colors in an EPS file?

Tags: color, images, eps, image-editing

I'm interested in buying a premade EPS file. I'd prefer that the EPS file illustration have colors changed (umbrella is in yellow, I'd like teal, etc.)

Does anyone know if EPS files allow color editing?

Comment: A simple google search would tell you that yes. If you use the search on this website you will find many other questions about editing EPS files with different tools.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "EPS" is too broad of a term... An EPS containing raster data **may not** be easy to edit. And EPS containing vector data **may** be easily edited. ---http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/85881/can-an-eps-file-contain-non-vectorized-fonts/85885#85885 -- There's no way to know with seeing the actual EPS.

Answer (score 2):

Every file format allows you to edit anything reasonably possible¹. Depending on what you want to do, it may be somewhat difficult, but changing the colour of a single-colour object is almost always easy. In case of an EPS with vector data, you may only need to change a handful of bytes and there are bazillion of programs available to help you do this.

Be aware that there also is a legal side to this, and whoever sells you that file may impose conditions upon you that you must not modify it or publish a modified version. This would somewhat render the purpose for which such files are usually bought moot, but you better take a look at the license.

---

<sup>¹ Unless you delve into the the realm file formats to be decrypted by rendering devices or closed-source software (digital rights management), but as far as I know, there is no variant of the EPS format that supports this and even if there were, the file you are buying should specify this.</sup>

Comment: However it may still not be easy for a beginner